# Custom meta for custom post type not importing / exporting

Tags: wordpress

When trying to export and then import using the wordpress built in export and the wordpress import plugin I have noticed custom meta for custom post types isn't being imported.

This is a real problem for me as i've spent alot of time working on a local version of site and I could do with the custom meta carrying over.

Has anyone else experienced this problem before as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange...However you can try exporting your database.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell doing my own tests, this happens because WordPress is creating existing custom fields (post meta) automatically when importing. Thus, you'll have duplicate values for the same field and WP will load the first one it sees, which might be the blank automatically created value. Because of the network installation I work with, I could only try this with version 3.1.2. It might be fixed in newer releases.

To fix it, you can put in the following code in your functions.php to remove post meta with a blank value for your custom keys.

```
function my_init() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE (`meta_key` = 'some_key' OR `meta_key` = 'another_key') AND `meta_value` = ''");
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

once your import is done, you can disable or remove this code.

Comment: this bug appears to be fixed in WP 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Try This addon for wordpress ctp plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/exportimport-custom-post-and-taxonomy-type/